# Syntax Error Regular Expresion, Unexpected token ')'

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código y no sé por qué está dando error

```javascript
function myFunction() }
    var str = "Visit W3Schools";
    var patt = /w3schools/i; 
    var result = str.match(patt);
   console.log(result,patt);
})
```

Me arroja el error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'
```

Comment: En la primera línea tienes un "}", que debería estar para el otro lado "{". En la última línea sobre el ")"

Answer (score 2):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Visit W3Schools";
    var patt = /w3schools/i;
    var result = str.match(patt);
    console.log(result,patt); 
}

myFunction()
```

Tienes un paréntesis de más al final de la declaración de la función y una llave mal puesta al principio

Comment: gracias , no entiendo, porque después de reparar el error me arroja result is not defined

Comment: function myFunction() {
    var str = "Visit W3Schools";
    var patt = /w3schools/i;
    var result = str.match(patt);
}
console.log(result);

Comment: Como podrás ver, en el snippet funciona todo correctamente, si ese es todo tu código sería ilógico que te arroje un error